# nsswitch.conf: is there a daemon I need to restart?

Tags: linux, nss, nsswitch.conf

When I modify /etc/nsswitch.conf,  is there an "nss" daemon I should restart?  I am not referring to modules such as mdns & nis.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No you probably don't (other than what David said, and maybe ypbind, but you said not NIS). The nsswitch.conf file isn't for a daemon in particular, it is actually a file used by the C library for various system calls.

Answer (score 25):

You may have nscd (Name Service Caching Daemon) running, which you may need to restart, otherwise it's unlikely. Certain daemons might cache get*() function call results and may need restarting.

Comment: Well since my answer as accepted I have to give David the upvote :-P

Comment: \o/ cheers. now I feel the need to upvote you for your generosity.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I can see that nscd isn't installed/running by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: That's probably a good thing. NSCD just normally causes more problems than it solves. :)

Comment: Rather than just restart, [you could disable the thing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273721/13308). I would restart my NSCD and successfully resolve host names, then a short while later, my resolution would fail. This happened consistently.

Answer (score 20):

Be aware that existing processes will not be aware of the changes to nsswitch.conf. The nsswitch.conf(5) page states, "Within  each  process  that uses nsswitch.conf, the entire file is read only once; if the file is later changed, the process will continue using the old configuration."

Comment: So what's a person to do?  Reboot?

Comment: @Ken: Sadly, this appears to be the case.

Comment: Installing `nscd` and doing `sudo service nscd restart && sudo service network-manager restart` removes the need to reboot for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 16: `Failed to restart nscd.service: Unit nscd.service not found`